# Creating a Button component in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux, react-typescript

I have to create a button component for my school project that should have an edit, cancel , save  ("Save" should be shown in dropdown when clicking "..."). Everything should be in typescript and i have never had experience with TS (only React). Can someone help me like where should I start and so on. Every little help is appreciated even if it's one line of code or a youtube channel. There is not so much info out there about TS.  This is what I have come up until now.

````
import React from "react";
//import "./Buttons.scss";

type Props = {
   color: string
   open: boolean
   //hideCancelBtn?: boolean
   isValid: boolean
   buttonTitle?: string;


};
export default function ButtonComponent (props: Props): JSX.Element {
   const {color, open, hideCancelBtn, isValid, buttonTitle } = props
}

//en handleclick function 
 
return (
<div className="AllButtons">
<div className="cancel">
<Button
           className="button button--grey button--row-margin"
           disabled={publishBtnInactive}
           onClick={onDraftClick}
         >
           cancel
         </Button>
</div>
.........
</div>



   
) ```
````

Comment: “There is not so much info out there about TS” Here’s an official guide: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react.html

Comment: The [TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/W48jAW) can be a great place to experiment and learn.

Comment: Writing React in TypeScript is not fundamentally different than writing it in plain JavaScript.  It's the same code but with some added annotations.  Start with figuring out the fundamentals of React and then deal with the TypeScript types.  Here's an example code that you can reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-buttons-cfpuh?file=/src/MyComponent.tsx